# SQL How can I convert MD5 Hash String to Binary using query?

Tags: sql, export, md5

In my project, I have a user table where password is MD5 hashed and stored as binary(16). Now I want to write those user data as INSERT queries to a .sql file so that customer can import them back again?

Or is there anyway to export those data directly? I tried DTS using from Excel to Access file but when importing, there are several errors occur that I don't know why? Or is there any other tool besides MSSQL Server that can do this?

So far, now I'm using detach/attach the whole database to send to the customer which I think is not really a good way?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone posted an answer to my question and deleted it right away? He suggested me to use [HASHBYTES](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx) which is exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks!